# how to activate GPS after get user location permission once in flutter

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart, gps, location

i want to enable GPS location automatically when user open application, user location permission granted when user install app. how i can activate location automatically in flutter?

```
Geolocator geolocator = Geolocator()..forceAndroidLocationManager;
Future<Position> getCurrentLocation() async {
    Position position = await geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    return position;
  }
```

Comment: Share with us the code that you've tried to activate the GPS automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Using [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) lib from **pub.dev** you can find the desired solution. After taking Location Permission from user by using your code just add 2 lines. Here is also a sample code.

```
import 'package:location/location.dart' as loc;

Future<Position> getCurrentLocation() async {
    loc.Location locationR = loc.Location();

    if (!await locationR.serviceEnabled()) {
      locationR.requestService();
    }
    Position position = await geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    return position;
  }
```

This 2 lines code check your GPS is turned ON/OFF. If OFF then it gives a prompt dialog to turn on GPS.